# Stuck at GRUB2 while installation Ubuntu on Windows 10 dual boot on 7560

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

When I got my PC, I succeeded to dual install Ubuntu with my Windows10. I followed [these](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) instructions and it worked successfully.
Unfortunately, I needed to format my computer. Windows 10 is installed successfully now. I tried to re-follow the same steps as before, but now I stuck at GRUB2 black screen. I even tried to disable the secure boot from the BIOS (UEFI). I also tried to change the SATA to AHCI. Except for getting stuck, I could not pogress the installation. Why at first time it worked and now not? What should I do to install the Ubuntu as dual boot to Windows 10 on my computer?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Are you booting in Safe mode and installing restricted drivers so you have nVidia driver installed?You must have AHCI not RAID and Windows fast start up/hibernation off.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: What  exactly do you mean that you get stuck at a black grub screen? Do you mean after you've finished the installation and reboot you get a [grub prompt screen](https://www.linux.org/threads/how-to-fix-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported-for-the-first-word-tab-lists-possible-command.30848/)?

Comment: The Ubuntu installation probably did not start (I saw the DELL screen) and the next screen I saw is the exact screen in your link.

Comment: It could just be that grub isn't installed properly and the rest of the system is ok. Need more detail. Boot to Live Ubuntu and run  `sudo parted -l`. Post output into your question. Make sure you line it up by applying { } around the highlighted output that is pasted.

Comment: You have an UEFI system, but hd0 is showing as MBR? Is that the live installer flash drive? And then it in UEFI boot mode. Rufus may create UEFI only or BIOS/MBR only flash drives &  you must have UEFI/gpt. You also are not showing Windows partitions?? You also may need newest version of Ubuntu since hardware is so new.

Comment: @PaulBenson My Ubuntu is not installed and  I can't enter it. The stuck occurs before even I can choose to install Ubuntu.

Comment: @oldfred, Yes I followed the instructions and already succeeded in installing UBUNTU at first time. After formatting, I can't install UBUNTU anymore and stuck in GRUB2.

Comment: @guiverc, I use Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, see above!

Comment: I wasn't asking you to boot into your installation. I asked you to boot up from **Live Ubuntu** then run a command. Are you now saying you can't even boot up from Live Ubuntu on your USB?

Comment: I repeated the instructions that I mentioned in the link above. The stage I stuck is running Ubuntu installation from USB.